# Como hacer para mostrar los acentos desde un archivo de javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp

Tengo un jsp en el cual se manda a llamar a un archivo de javascript de la siguiente manera

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/webresorces/js/validacion.js" />"></script>
```

El archivo js contiene las validaciones de los campos del formulario que esta en mi jsp, tengo algo como esto

```js
var validator = $("#consulta").validate({ 
  rules: {
    idPago:{        
      number: true,
      maxlenght: 16
    }
  },
  messages:{
    idPago{
       number: "El campo debe ser num\u00e9rico",
       maxlenght: "El campo debe ser de 6 posiciones"
    }

  }
})
```

el problema es que no toma los acentos, salen caracteres raros, y es que anteriormente este código para validar los campos lo tenia dentro del jsp y ponia los acentos normales y si los tomaba, 
pero al colocar la validación en un archivo externo ya no salen bien

que puede ser?
ya probé colocando las palabras con el acento normal y usando en unicode 
pero ninguno los toma

Comment: debes asegurarte que en tu html en meta este cotejado en utf-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para asegurarte de que tu JSP genera un HTML con UTF-8, debes añadir en la primera línea del archivo .jsp lo siguiente:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Agrega `utf-8` en tu pagina

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
```

Comment: es que mi jsp esta usando un template y no tiene como tal esas etiquetas

Comment: @Root93 creo que te equivocas, jsp es como html pero compila codigo java o algo asi, jamas lo use